# Visual Studio doesn't show full array when when dynamically creating array of pointers

Tags: c++, visual-studio, pointers, debugging

My code:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

   int main()
   {
      char** pptr = new char*[5];

      for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      pptr[i] = new char[5];
   }
```

What I want to happen is that `pptr` now points to the beginning of an array of 5 pointers that each point to the beginning of an array of 5 characters.

I put a breakpoint at the end of the main function and added `pptr` to watch, and it only stores one pointer. Why does this happen and how do I do it correctly?

[image]

Comment: You said you wanted `pptr` to point to the *beginning* of an array of pointers... the *beginning* of an array is indeed **one** pointer - the *first* one in the *array*. The other pointers come later in the same array.

Comment: Please next time reduce the picture to its interesting part to not have that large white margin ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the default knowledge of your pointer type in Visual Studio. You indicate in the code that `char** pptr` is a pointer, but it cannot know how big.

To fix this, you can add a watch on `pptr[0]`, and then you can specify that it has a "size" of 5 by changing it to `pptr[0],5`. Also, if the size is variable you can do "ptr[0],[size]" where size is an expression that evaluates to the number of elements to show.

Comment: That's an interesting solution to an annoying problem, I'll try it out in the future. Though I'm surprised, since `pptr[0],5` has a distinct meaning in c++. It seems inconsistent for the debugger to arbitrarily interpret certain operators differently when it treats most operators the same way the language does.

Comment: Yes, the `,` is specific to the debugger watch variable. I'm not sure it works with a comma operator as the expression. Probably triggeres a bunch of errors somewhere!

Comment: yes is strange, is it not possible to change the type of the element to display to be `char*[5]` being c++ as I proposed ? (I do not use Visual Studio)

Comment: No, it only displays the type as VS understands it. But then, you can always have a `reinterprect_cast` in the expression as well (I think).

Comment: @SoronelHaetir thanks a lot for the enhancement, I didn't know about that one!

Comment: Yes, you should be able to dereference the pointer and cast it to a reference to an array of 5 `char*` which I think is written `char*(&)[5]`. Edit : The watch expression `(char*(&)[5])(*pptr)` will give you `pptr` as an array of 5 `char*`. Edit 2 : Though `pptr,5` is still a way nicer way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

Your program does what you want, but the debugger cannot know the number of elements, it just know it is a pointer, so it write the contains of that pointer.

I don't know what debugger you use, but probably when you display the values you can modify `char**` by char*[5]` to see all

Answer (score -2):

```
// #include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    char** pptr = new char*[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        pptr[i] = new char[5];

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        char ch='A';
        pptr[0][i]=ch;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        cout<<pptr[0][i]<<" ";
    }
}
```

Now the pptr[0] that is a pointer is pointing to an array of characters. Hope that it helps.

Comment: the problem doesn't concern the code but what the debugger shows by default